# NativeDaemonFailureException in com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector

Tags: android, exception

I have a problem and the exception information is below. Is there anybody who know what may cause that?

```
android.util.Log$TerribleFailure: problem removing interface quota
    at android.util.Log.wtf(Log.java:291)
    at android.util.Log.wtf(Log.java:286)
    at com.android.server.net.NetworkPolicyManagerService.removeInterfaceQuota(NetworkPolicyManagerService.java:2235)
    at com.android.server.net.NetworkPolicyManagerService.updateNetworkRulesLocked(NetworkPolicyManagerService.java:1274)
    at com.android.server.net.NetworkPolicyManagerService$13.onReceive(NetworkPolicyManagerService.java:1044)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:864)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '1799 bandwidth removeiquota rmnet_data0' failed with '400 1799 Bandwidth command failed'
    at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.removeInterfaceQuota(NetworkManagementService.java:1630)
    at com.android.server.net.NetworkPolicyManagerService.removeInterfaceQuota(NetworkPolicyManagerService.java:2233)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector$NativeDaemonFailureException: command '1799 bandwidth removeiquota rmnet_data0' failed with '400 1799 Bandwidth command failed'
    at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.execute(NativeDaemonConnector.java:431)
    at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.executeForList(NativeDaemonConnector.java:367)
    at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.execute(NativeDaemonConnector.java:332)
    at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.removeInterfaceQuota(NetworkManagementService.java:1628)
```

Comment: did you get any solution to this problem?